# Как сгенерировать список используемых на странице цветов и шрифтов?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Нужно составить полный список всех цветов border, background, цветов текста и т.п. и найти отклонения. Например, в каком-то элементе на странице border другого оттенка, где-то шрифт не тот что везде. Есть ли какие-то плагины/скрипты для этого?

Comment: Для удобства используется что-то типа sass и такие проблемы обычно отпадают.
Так же в css можно использовать переменные.
А для того чтобы собрать палитру того что сейчас есть гуглите плагины для браузера, наверняка должны быть.

Comment: понятно как таких проблем избегать, но тут ситуация в которой они уже есть. Плагин для браузера видел для старых firefox, в принципе не проблема и сейчас такую версию поставить и плагин установить. Название его нужно, например.

Comment: http://webcolourdata.com

Comment: There was an error with processing that website 
+ есть локальный сайт, который так не проверить. Но направление то

Comment: ну локальный можно выгрузить, пару сайтов прогнал через сервис - вроде всё норм работает, больше даже ХЗ чем помочь :-(